# Is FPGA more cost effective than GPU?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware

Actually is there a list of hardware we could use and their bitcoins/hardware price ratio so I can compute return of investment?

Comment: You should read Butterfly Labs' announcement of ASIC equipment under development and take it into consideration in your projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPGAs in general cost more initially per given computational speed, but use less power per MHash/s. Currently, the good GPUs have a faster return of investment time, but they are highly dependant on difficulty and Bitcoin price.

To be more specific, find your desired hardware in the ["Mining Hardware Comparison"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) wiki page, and then do some calculations (you can for example use [my mining calculator](http://tpbitcalc.appspot.com)).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very detailed list of known mining hardware and it's mining-specific specifications:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison